# how to find longest match of a string including a focus word in python

Tags: python, string, match, pseudocode

new to python/programming, so not quite sure how to phrase this....

What I want to do is this: input a sentence, find all matches of the input sentence and a set of stored sentences/strings, and return the longest combination of matched strings.

I think the answer will have something to do with regex, but I haven't started those yet and didn't want to if i didn't need to.

My question: is regex the way to go about this? or is there a way to do this without importing anything?

if it helps you understand my question/idea, heres pseudocode for what i'm trying to do:

```
input = 'i play soccer and eat pizza on the weekends'
focus_word = 'and'

ss = [
      'i play soccer and baseball',
      'i eat pizza and apples',
      'every day i walk to school and eat pizza for lunch',
      'i play soccer but eat pizza on the weekend',
     ]

match = MatchingFunction(input, focus_word, ss)
# input should match with all except ss[3]

ss[0]match= 'i play soccer and'
ss[1]match = 'and'
ss[2]match = 'and eat pizza'

#the returned value match should be 'i play soccer and eat pizza'
```

Comment: This sounds like homework... Can you show us what you've tried? StackOverflow can be used to ask for homework help - but you have to have made an effort first!

Comment: isn't homework...haha doing this for fun. What i have so far is an input() to type in a sentence, a database to store a set of all inputs (set so theres no duplicates) and then a function to iterate through the database and find if i==input. I wasn't sure where to start with the keyword part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find the [longest common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring) between your input string and each string in your database. Assuming you have a function LCS that will find the longest common substring of two strings, you could do something like:

```
> [LCS(input, s) for s in ss]
['i play soccer and ',
 ' eat pizza ',
 ' and eat pizza ',
 ' eat pizza on the weekend']
```

Then, it sounds like you're looking for the *most-repeated* substring within your list of strings. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not quite sure what you're looking for in the general case!) From the array output above, what combination of strings would you use to create your output string?

---

Based on your comments, I think this should do the trick:

```
> parts = [s for s in [LCS(input, s) for s in ss] if s.find(focus_word) > -1]
> parts
['i play soccer and ', ' and eat pizza ']
```

Then, to get rid of the duplicate words in this example:

```
> "".join([parts[0]] + [p.replace(focus_word, "").strip() for p in parts[1:]])
'i play soccer and eat pizza'
```

Comment: Thanks! longest common substring looks close to what i'm after.(if not exactly!) The final result i'm trying to get when keyword is 'and' is the longest match that only have 'and' in them. So from the array output you gave, i would only want ['i play soccer and','and eat pizza'].

Comment: i tested this on a few different sets of strings and the only problem is the join statement at the end. if input = 'see the dog run away' and key_word = 'the'  and ss = ['see dog run','see the dog','see the dog run fast','see dog run away','the dog is fat','look its the dog'], I get this:

>>> parts
['see the dog', 'see the dog run ', 'the dog ', ' the dog']

>>> "".join([parts[0]] + [p.replace(b, "").strip() for p in parts[1:]])
'see the dogsee  dog rundogdog'

--thats fine tho- this isn't as important as getting the parts